# Nested environment: same counter value before and after

Tags: environments

I'd like to generate "labels" to use at the beginning and at the end of an environment. Unfortunately the value of the counter is modified between the start and the end of the environment:

[image]

Any idea how I could avoid that issue?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcounter{nextMarkId}

\newenvironment{subproof}{\thenextMarkId\stepcounter{nextMarkId}}{\thenextMarkId}

\begin{document}

\begin{subproof}
  \begin{subproof}
    blabla
  \end{subproof}
\end{subproof}

I'd like to have: 0 1 blabla 1 0

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The proposed answer does not work because I want the label of each environment to be unique:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcounter{nextMarkId}

\newenvironment{subproof}
{\thenextMarkId\stepcounter{nextMarkId}}
{\addtocounter{nextMarkId}{-1}\thenextMarkId}

\begin{document}

\begin{subproof}
  \begin{subproof}
    blabla
  \end{subproof}
  \begin{subproof}
    blabla
  \end{subproof}
\end{subproof}

I'd like to have: 0 1 blabla 1 2 blabla 2 0

\end{document}
```

[image]

I was thinking to use some sort of stack... but it seems quite ugly.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not really clear what you want to achieve. Should the next batch of nested `subproof` environments always start with 0?

Comment: No, each `subproof` environment should have a different label (or maybe I should call it an identifier). Basically I just want to assign a different identifier to each environment to be able to address them individually later.

Comment: OK, that's what the answer below obtains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the current value and use it at the end of the environment. Since environments form groups, this will do the right thing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcounter{nextMarkId}

\newenvironment{subproof}
  {\thenextMarkId\edef\thisMarkId{\thenextMarkId}\stepcounter{nextMarkId}}
  {\thisMarkId}

\begin{document}

\begin{subproof}
  \begin{subproof}
    blabla
  \end{subproof}
\end{subproof}

I'd like to have: 0 1 blabla 1 0

\begin{subproof}
  \begin{subproof}
    blabla
    \begin{subproof}
      blabla
    \end{subproof}
  \end{subproof}
  \begin{subproof}
    blabla
  \end{subproof}
\end{subproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, good point, I was not thinking it would work, I forgot environment form groups. Thanks!